# Jhipster project : prod profile doesn't generate files in Dist folder

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, jhipster

I am working on a project  generated with Jhipster 2.1.1

When I package with Prod profile, if I check the files that are generated in Dist folder, I only see the files that were generated during the creation of the project (files that were generated by jhipster generator).

All the scripts that were created after the first generation of the project(when I created entities) are not in the dist folder, and the one that have been updated (navbar for example) stay in their original version.

Is it a known issue or something I should configure in my project in order to make the prod package work successfully?

Thank you.

Comment: This version is no longer supported so I'm afraid you might be on your own here. In prod build, the dist folder should nto contain your original files, it should contain one file that is minified and versioned and is the concatenation of all your files. same thing for your bower dependencies.

Comment: too bad, I should have asked my question one month ago :) So I need to figure out why grunt doesnt put my html views and js scripts into /dist/xxxxxapp.js

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and it was due to having unclosed single quotes in custom  html files. As a result the grunt task useminPrepare failed.

Comment: You saw a failed statement in your logs? in my logs I don't have any error.

Comment: It was some time ago and I remember having a tricky time working out what was going on.  Try running `grunt -dv build' and pipe the output to a file.  Check to see if the final task (htmlmin) completes. 
It will probably be some invalid html (e.g. no end tag, extra quotation mark etc) that is causing your issue.

Comment: you may be right. I have run grunt -dv build.  grunt stays stuck at this line :"Reading src/main/webapp/scripts/components/navbar/navbar.html...OK"
The process is working 100% but nothing happens (since 10 min at least). I don't know how to find the htmll file that is causing this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean you don't know how to find the html file that is causing the issue, just navigate to the src/main/webapp/scripts/components/navbar folder, it will be in there.  Once you do, update your original post with the navbar.html file and I will try and find out the issue.

Comment: Also the log line you included appears in two places, so can you include which task is failing, is it the copy:dist or the ngtemplates task?

Comment: I have only one html file in navbar folder : navbar.html. AS there is a OK status on this file I guess the problem is somewhere else. Other files  in this folder are : navbar.controller.js and navbar.directive.js.

Comment: the task is : Running "ngtemplates:dist" (ngtemplates) task
This task seems to read all the html files.

Comment: The next step in ngtemplates task will put your html files in a file called templates.js.  This is where it is hanging.  

There is a github issue that talks about this, basically as I have mentioned it is invariably due to some incorrect html

https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates/issues/110

Comment: I can now reproduce the issue by adding an extra whitespace and " char at the end of a tag e.g. <span
                                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" ">

I would do a search for " "> or " "/> and see if you find anything.

Comment: I have the exact same issue right now. "grunt -dv build" struck after placing  this line on the console, "Reading src/main/webapp/scripts/components/navbar/navbar.html...OK"

Comment: @Narendra - did you try searching your project for " "> or " "/>

Comment: @GrantLay - I got the issue fixed. ngtemplates was just getting hung after navbar.html & I have no issue with navbar.html. Then I have just tried to execute the task "htmlmin" & it did stuck at the file which has issue & you are right an extra space was the issue. So sad, a small mistake has resulted in few hours to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

GrantLay is right (& I have upvoted it).
However, just to elaborate (as having all this in comments, would look clumsy)

Grunt (ngtemplates task) on angular templates is hanging - if there is an issue with the format of any of the html files.

As GrantLay rightly mentioned - most of the time, the issue is either with the structure of the Html (tags), extra quotes.

ngtemplates would show the errors corresponding to tags - but for those extra quotes it just hangs - without giving a hint w.r.t which file has caused the issue.

So, I tried to verify the issues using htmllint ( https://github.com/htmllint/grunt-htmllint)

But, it gave me so many errors that it is an uphill (& almost impossible) task to go through all those errors.

Then, I have removed other tasks and has just run htmlmin (& yes in verbose mode)
htmlmin has stuck at the file which has issue.

May be running htmllint on just that file alone - might eliminate the manual work of going through each line (Somehow, I just took the manual route to find the issue.)